# Firebase Delete All Node Based on a Particular Value in Android

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I have below Firebase Database Structure. I need to delete all the node based on a particular child value match.

[image]

I have written below code where I am saving the child `dp` value in `ref` variable then added a SingleValueEvent listener and based on the snapshot trying to delete but it is deleting all the node regardless of child value

```
 mDatabase= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("my_reference");

 mDatabase.orderByChild("dP").equalTo(ref).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

 @Override
 public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

     mDatabase.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).removeValue();

     }
 }

 @Override
 public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

   }
 });
```

Comment: `mDatabase.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("name").removeValue();`
`mDatabase.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).child("dp").removeValue();`

**do for all five child**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you're deleting with:

```
 mDatabase.child(dataSnapshot.getKey()).removeValue();
```

If you parse the path here, you'll see it makes sense that it deletes the entire node. What you want is:

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

    datas.getRef().removeValue();

  }
}
```